# R: how to use the Hodges-Lehman estimator?

Tags: r, statistics, statistical-test

"The [Hodges-Lehmann estimator](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/DescTools/html/HodgesLehmann.html) is the median of the combined data points and Walsh averages". In my data I have the data points `before` and `after`. I understand that the Hodges-Lehman estimator gives me a median of these data points combined. Am I correct? And how should this be coded? This try results in the error "unused argument (after = NULL)"

```
df %>% HodgesLehmann(before, after = NULL, conf.level = NA, na.rm = FALSE)
```

My data

```
structure(list(condition = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
                                      2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
                                      2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
                                      1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
                                      2, 1), before = c(13, 7, 18, 18, 15, 5, 14, 5, 3, 6, 
                                                        18, 7, 5, 11, 6, 3, NA, 3, 11, 8, 10, 3, 7, 7, 12, 3, 5, 8, 4, 
                                                        9, 15, 9, 3, 16, 3, 3, 11, 3, 11, 8, 14, 21, 21, 17, 9, 3, 18, 
                                                        15, 6, 6, 12, 9, 15, 5, 13, 7, 6, 7, 9, 11, 21, 12, 7, 12, 6, 
                                                        21, 15, 21, 16, 12, 7, 18, 12, 20, 3, 10), after = c(15, 
                                                                                                             3, 6, 18, 14, 15, 6, NA, 6, 3, 18, NA, 3, 15, NA, 15, 11, NA, 
                                                                                                             10, 9, NA, 6, 6, 12, 3, NA, NA, 11, 9, 15, 21, 21, 6, 15, 9, 
                                                                                                             16, 9, 11, 14, 13, 5, NA, 3, 10, NA, 3, 18, 12, NA, NA, 8, 11, 
                                                                                                             14, NA, 13, NA, NA, 10, 6, 5, 15, 11, 12, NA, 5, NA, 15, 21, 
                                                                                                             11, NA, 3, NA, 12, NA, 17, 15)), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                        "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -76L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                          .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 76L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -76L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
HodgesLehmann(before,conf.level = .95, na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**